# SSL Handshake time is higher in JMeter than locust tool

Tags: ssl, jmeter, ssl-certificate, performance-testing

We have observed higher SSL handshakes for one our API's in JMeter load testing.The 95% of the API is around 105ms.We did the load testing on same API on same load generator with locust tool.Surprisingly, the P95 response is around 40ms.

This is the first time I have observed huge difference in response times between two tools
SSL Handshake in JMeter is taking too much time and is quite visible in the tcp dump.How to resolve this SSL Handshake time issue in JMeter.We have use Httpclient4 as client implementation in the request

We also tried setting all ssl options like https.default.protocol,https.socket.protocols,https.use.cached.ssl.context,httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration,httpclient4.idletimeout,httpclient4.validate_after_inactivity.

Please let me know how to resolve this ssl taking higher time issue in jmeter

Comment: If you already have a TCP dump have you compared the timing and package content of the two unit testing tools (e.g. in Wireshark)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Well-behaved load testing tools must report the same or nearly the same timings for the same actions.
2. You should compare not Locust to JMeter but Locust to the real browser (or other API consumer)

With regards to SSL handshake, if you really have the proof that it is longer in JMeter than in other HTTP client - you can [raise an issue for JMeter project](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) and describe your findings there.

I tried to reproduce your issue using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool with 10 virtual users and 100 iterations hitting https://example.com website and got 0.09 for JMeter and 0.095 for Locust which is pretty much in line with what Firefox browser and tools like cURL report.

Taurus scripts just in case you want to play yourself:

```
#JMeter
execution:
  - executor: jmeter
    concurrency: 10
    iterations: 100
    scenario: request_example

scenarios:
  request_example:
    requests:
      - https://example.com
```

and

```
#Locust
execution:
  - executor: locust
    concurrency: 10
    iterations: 100
    scenario: request_example

scenarios:
  request_example:
    default-address: https://example.com
    requests:
      - url: /
        method: get
```

Comment: We have done a lot of load testings with jmeter ,we never had issues with response times.Recently we migrated to GCP.We are having issues with JMeter hitting GLB.On Locust results are too good.We did a test on Akamai too.Akamai support team has raised raised concerns with SSL handshake.

Comment: the response times are higher when I'm using httpclient4.While using java client implementation,resonse times are far better.However p90 still way higher than locust tool